# I've removed .class file from my project in eclipse thinking it'll be regenerated again. But it didn't

Tags: java, eclipse

From my eclipse project I've removed .class file for a particular class thinking eclipse will regenerate it for me if I build it again or run the project again.

But when I tried to run the program, It's showing class not found exception.
I'm wondering what's happening there? doesn't eclipse build .class files each time we run the project? when compilation will happen in eclipse?

Comment: check in menu  Project--> Build automatically is enabled

Comment: Check this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327570/re-building-a-deleted-class-file-in-eclipse).

Comment: @Karthigeyan yes it's enabled

Comment: Try refreshing (F5) the project in Eclipse with the missing .class

Answer (score 3):

Compilation will happen either the next time the source file is modified, if you have it set to Build Automatically, or the next time you run. *Both* of these expect compiled source files to still have their .class files around. *Clean* the project from the `Project` menu to force it to recompile regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in the Project up-menu, the option "Build Automatically" is checked then just clean your project.
It should regenerate the .class file(s).

Answer (score 0):

Check Your java file is in a source folder (right click project, properties, build path)

and you have automatic build turned on (Project menu -> Build automatically)

Also make sure your project compilation/build succeeds, otherwise Eclipse may not compile all the classes.
Check in the Problem windows if there is any error on the project compilation then fix it first.

Answer (score 0):

- Project menu
- Click "Clean"
- Select "clean all projects" or "Clean selected projects below" and
  choose your project
- Check "Start a build immediately"
- Click "ok"
- Now run your program.

Also as suggested by other answers, enable "Build Automatically" in Projects Menu.

Hope it helps